# Specific issue with git cloning through ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to npm install a private package from my companies git repository.

I have access to this repository and can successfully clone the repository using

```
git clone git@github.com:Company/path-to-repo.git
```

when I run `npm install`, it tries to use

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com:Company/path-to-repo.git
```

which is when I get this error back:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I also get the same error if I manually type `git clone ssh://git@github.com:Company/path-to-repo.git` in my terminal.

Also, I have succesfully set up ssh keys for my github account and this machine, running `ssh -T git@github.com` returns successful.

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation for why the clone isn't working, but because I don't know `npm` this does not include a suggestion for for fixing it.

The `:` after the `user@host` component makes this an invalid URL:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com:Company/path-to-repo.git
```

Like any other URL, the format of the network location is `[user@]host[:port]`, and `:Company` looks nothing like a valid port specification.

For that to work, it needs to be:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/Company/path-to-repo.git
```